# AppStore.sync() not restoring purchases

Tags: ios, swift, macos, in-app-purchase, storekit

On an app that was using the old API for In-App Purchases (*StoreKit 1*). The app is already published on the App Store. The purchase is **non-consumable**.

While trying to migrate to *StoreKit 2*, I'm unable to restore purchases.
Specifically displaying and purchasing products works as expected, but when deleting and reinstalling the app, and then trying to restore purchases I can't do it.

I'm trying to restore them using the new APIs but it doesn't seem to be working.
What I have tried so far:

I'm listening for transaction updates during the whole lifetime of the app, with:

```swift
Task.detached {
    for await result in Transaction.updates {
        if case let .verified(safe) = result {

        }
    }
}
```

I have a button that calls this method, but other than prompting to log in again with the Apple ID it doesn't seem to have any effect at all:

```swift
try? await AppStore.sync()
```

This doesn't return any item

```swift
for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
    if case let .verified(transaction) = result {

    }
}
```

This doesn't return any item

```swift
for await result in Transaction.all {
    if case let .verified(transaction) = result {

    }
}
```

As mentioned before I'm trying this after purchasing the item and deleting the app. So I'm sure it should be able to restore the purchase.
Am trying this both with a **Configuration.storekit** file on the simulator, and without it on a real device, in the Sandbox Environment.

Has anyone being able to restore purchases using StoreKit 2?

Ps: I already filed a feedback report on *Feedback Assistant*, but so far the only thing that they have replied is:

> Because StoreKit Testing in Xcode is a local environment, and the data is tied to the app, when you delete the app you're also deleting all the transaction data for that app in the Xcode environment. The code snippets provided are correct usage of the API.

So yes, using a **Configuration.storekit** file won't work on restoring purchases, but if I can't restore them on the Sandbox Environment I'm afraid that this won't work once released, leaving my users totally unable to restore what they have already purchased.

Comment: So is this app iOS or macOS? You've tagged both.

Comment: I am working on an app now `currentEntitlements` works on iOS, with test flight. I cannot get it to work on watchOS, but testing on watchOS is not documented, if I go through the purchase process again it restores but that isnt a good ux. I haven't tried macOS.

Comment: @DávidPásztor it is both, iOS and macOS.

Comment: @loremipsum For me too, trying to purchase again restores any previous purchase, but I agree with you, it is not desirable. Will try with TestFlight, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Jesus man, Apple... In my case `currentEntitlements` started working ONLY (as I was migrating to StoreKit2) after I called first time `AppStore.sync()`.

Comment: @sabiland I found really difficult to test and make it work myself too, but once I made it working is great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Update for iOS 17

On iOS 17 we have a new API to take care of this integrated in `SwiftUI` [currentEntitlementTask(for:priority:action:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/productview/4211574-currententitlementtask)

It handles this much more easily and with just a few lines of code.
I can also validate that it works both on **Release** and **Debug** mode.

#### Example

```swift
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// your view
        }
        .currentEntitlementTask(for: "My Purchase ID") { state in
            guard
                let transaction = state.transaction,
                case .verified(let verified) = transaction
            else { return }
            /// ...
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to **import** `StoreKit` to be able to use this `View Modifier`.

## Original answer

#### Pre iOS 17

After releasing to the **App Store** and finally trying the app directly in production I can confirm that it works, but I have to say that it is **not ideal** to be unable to test this on the *sandbox environment*.

Also I feel the documentation was not clear enough, at least not for me.
Probably it is clear for other folks, but I was expecting the purchases to be restored automatically and get them on `for await result in Transaction.updates`, but this didn't work.

What did work was to check `Transaction.currentEntitlements`, and if the entitlement is not there, then do a `sync()` and check again.
This is the code that worked for me:

```swift
try? await AppStore.sync()
        
for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
    if case let .verified(transaction) = result {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### Caveats

- As mentioned before, this only works on `release mode` and doesn't work on `debug mode` without **StoreKit Testing**, that is without a `Configuration.storekit`.
- If you want to use **StoreKit Testing** (using a `Configuration.storekit`) restoring purchases works (with this same approach), but only if you don't delete de app and reinstall again. By deleting the app you loose StoreKit Testing history.
- As mentioned by @loremipsum, this can be tested on TestFlight too (for it being release mode).
- Verified both iOS and macOS.

Comment: I am Trying the same thing and am stuck on restore purchases. Are you able to do it then please let me know thanks

Comment: The only problem is that `AppStore.sync()` always ask for AppleId password?

Comment: @sabiland Exactly, nothing bad at calling `AppStore.synch()` other than users will be prompted to login. Apple recommends only using it when really necessary as it might annoy users.

Comment: @vauxhall yeah, but how do you know 100% when is "really necessary"?

Comment: @sabiland the way I do it is with a flag, if the user wants to restore purchases I check for `currentEntitlements` first. If the user tries again I do `synch()` and check for entitlements after.

Comment: Yep, understood, I am doing the same. And I like to do this first procedure (check possible restore scenario) first even if user taps Purchase button (mistakenly). That's why I asked you about 100% etc. :)