# StoreKit StoreView restore purchase listener

Tags: swift, storekit

I use StoreKit's StoreView to buy in-app purchases. The purchase is working in the simulator, but how can I restore purchases? I did not find a restore handler, there is only a `onInAppPurchaseCompletion` but I'm missing a `onRestorePurchaseCompletion` or similar.

This is how it looks

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is my code:

```
  StoreView(ids: ["my.product.id"])
   .storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases)
   .storeButton(.hidden, for: .cancellation)
   .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
    if case .success(.success(let transaction)) = result {
       print("Purchased successfully: \(transaction.signedDate)")
       isPremium = true
    } else {
       print("Something went wrong")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using StoreKit 2 UI the Restore Purchases button behaves the same as calling `AppStore.sync()`

This refetches the entitlements from App Store. There is thus no handler for it provided, as any missing entitlements should be added as a successfully completed purchase on the `onInAppPurchaseCompletion` handler. Additionally, any missing entitlements will also be added into the `Transaction.currentEntitlements` after user clicks the button and authenticates on the App Store.

You can read more about this behaviour in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69896091/13172452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789119/use-storebutton-in-a-productview).

Comment: How can I test a restore of a non-consumable item? When I make a purchase in simulator, then the buy button is grayed out - as expected. After deleting and reinstalling the app, I can buy it again (I would expect an error like "you already own this product". A click on restore does nothing.

Comment: If you use StoreKit Testing in Xcode, then you should use the testing configurations described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/testing-in-app-purchases-with-storekit-transaction-manager-in-code). You may for example set network error on purchase and try restoring the purchase using the restore button to test your functionality. Uninstalling the application will disassociate previous transaction from the app, as described [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657081).